# VLC RTSP live stream to Android

Tags: android, stream, vlc, rtsp

For my app I have to stream from a decklink card to an Android app (I must be a live stream, so either HLS or RTSP seems to be good solutions, since my app targets Android 3+). I recompiled VLC with the decklink sdk, and I am able to live stream to another pc over the network (but it works only 60sec with RTSP).

Here is what I tried :

- HTTP Stream :

  ```
  ./vlc -vvv decklink:// --sout
  '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=56,ab=24,channels=1}
  :standard{access=http{use-key-frames},mux=ts,dst=:3001/stream.mpeg}'
  ```

It is working in Android VLC 0.0.11, but only in WiFi, not in 3G. And I am not able to play it in my app with a VideoView. Here is the code I used and the corresponding error messages :

```
String url = "http://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.mpeg";

VideoView videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));        
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.requestFocus();  
videoView.start();
```

Error messages :

```
04-08 15:26:46.272: D/MediaPlayer(16349): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-08 15:26:46.272: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(7680): connect on behalf of uid 1080867789
04-08 15:26:46.272: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(7680): connect to http://134.246.63.169:8554/ @0
04-08 15:26:46.302: I/AwesomePlayer(7680): AwesomePlayer::AwesomePlayer()in
04-08 15:26:46.302: I/AwesomePlayer(7680): AwesomePlayer::AwesomePlayer()aftermClient.connect()
04-08 15:26:46.302: I/AwesomePlayer(7680): setDataSource_l('http://134.246.63.169:5554/')
04-08 15:26:46.302: W/MediaPlayer(16349): info/warning (701, 0)
04-08 15:26:46.302: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(7680): connect on behalf of uid 10067
04-08 15:26:46.302: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(7680): connect to http://134.246.63.169:5554/ @0
04-08 15:26:46.342: I/ActivityManager(272): Displayed fr.ifremer.testrtsp/.MainActivity: +183ms
04-08 15:26:46.382: I/MediaPlayer(16349): Info (701,0)
04-08 15:27:07.592: E/MediaPlayer(16349): error (1, -2147483648)
04-08 15:27:07.592: E/MediaPlayer(16349): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

- RTSP :

I used the encoding options recommended by Google on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), eg :

- video codec : h264
- audio codec : AAC
- video bitrate : 56
- audio bitrate : 24
- audio channels : 1
- size : 176x144

  ```
  ./vlc -vvv decklink:// --sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2 --sout
  '#transcode{width=176,height=144,vcodec=h264,acodec=mp4a,vb=56,ab=24,channels=1}
  :rtp{dst=134.246.63.169,port-video=5554,port-audio=5556,sdp=rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp}'
  ```

I am able to play the stream in VLC desktop, but not in Android (even in the Android VLC version or the default Google video player:/ ).
If I don't specify a muxer, I can also play it it QuickTime (if I specify the muxer, either ts or ps, I have no video. If I try another muxer, VLC tells me that I am only allowed to use ts or ps in RTP)

If I try with the Google video player, I get these messages in the locat :

```
04-08 15:32:45.792: D/MediaPlayer(13688): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-08 15:32:45.802: W/MediaPlayer(13688): info/warning (701, 0)
04-08 15:32:45.812: I/MediaPlayer(13688): Info (701,0)
04-08 15:32:45.812: D/MediaPlayer(13688): getMetadata
04-08 15:32:45.812: E/MediaPlayerService(7680): getMetadata failed -38
04-08 15:32:45.852: I/MyHandler(7680): connection request completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/MyHandler(7680): DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): v=0
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): o=- 15352003113363922923 15352003113363922923 IN IP4 to63-169.ifremer.fr
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): s=Unnamed
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): i=N/A
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): c=IN IP4 134.246.63.169
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): t=0 0
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=tool:vlc 2.0.5
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=recvonly
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=type:broadcast
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=charset:UTF-8
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=control:rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): m=audio 5556 RTP/AVP 96
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=AS:24
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=RR:0
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/48000
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5; profile-level-id=15; mode=AAC-hbr; config=118856e500; SizeLength=13; IndexLength=3; IndexDeltaLength=3; Profile=1;
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=control:rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp/trackID=0
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): m=video 5554 RTP/AVP 96
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=AS:56
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=RR:0
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64000b;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAC6zZQsTv/AC0ALBAAAADAEAAAAyjxQplgA==,aOvssiw=;
04-08 15:32:45.882: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=control:rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp/trackID=1
04-08 15:32:45.982: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-08 15:32:45.982: I/MyHandler(7680): SETUP(1) completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:45.982: I/MyHandler(7680): server specified timeout of 60 secs.
04-08 15:32:45.992: W/MyHandler(7680): Missing 'source' field in Transport response. Using RTSP endpoint address.
04-08 15:32:45.992: I/APacketSource(7680): dimensions 176x144
04-08 15:32:46.012: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-08 15:32:46.022: I/MyHandler(7680): SETUP(2) completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:46.022: I/MyHandler(7680): server specified timeout of 60 secs.
04-08 15:32:46.022: W/MyHandler(7680): Missing 'source' field in Transport response. Using RTSP endpoint address.
04-08 15:32:46.022: W/MyHandler(7680): Server picked an odd RTP port, it should've picked an even one, we'll let it pass for now, but this may break in the future.
04-08 15:32:46.082: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-08 15:32:46.082: D/dalvikvm(13688): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 303K, 7% free 9289K/9927K, paused 35ms, total 36ms
04-08 15:32:46.092: I/MyHandler(7680): PLAY completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:46.092: I/MyHandler(7680): This is a live stream
04-08 15:32:48.262: D/AudioHardware(7680): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
04-08 15:32:48.262: D/AudioHardware(7680): closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
04-08 15:32:56.092: W/MyHandler(7680): Never received any data, switching transports.
04-08 15:32:56.112: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-08 15:32:56.122: I/MyHandler(7680): TEARDOWN completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:56.122: I/MyHandler(7680): connection request completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/MyHandler(7680): DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): v=0
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): o=- 15352003157473632156 15352003157473632156 IN IP4 to63-169.ifremer.fr
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): s=Unnamed
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): i=N/A
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): c=IN IP4 134.246.63.169
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): t=0 0
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=tool:vlc 2.0.5
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=recvonly
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=type:broadcast
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=charset:UTF-8
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=control:rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): m=audio 5556 RTP/AVP 96
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=AS:24
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=RR:0
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/48000
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5; profile-level-id=15; mode=AAC-hbr; config=118856e500; SizeLength=13; IndexLength=3; IndexDeltaLength=3; Profile=1;
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=control:rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp/trackID=0
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): m=video 5554 RTP/AVP 96
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=AS:56
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): b=RR:0
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64000b;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAC6zZQsTv/AC0ALBAAAADAEAAAAyjxQplgA==,aOvssiw=;
04-08 15:32:56.152: I/ASessionDescription(7680): a=control:rtsp://134.246.63.169:5554/stream.sdp/trackID=1
04-08 15:32:56.222: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported transport
04-08 15:32:56.222: I/MyHandler(7680): SETUP(1) completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:56.222: I/APacketSource(7680): dimensions 176x144
04-08 15:32:56.242: I/ARTSPConnection(7680): status: RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported transport
04-08 15:32:56.252: I/MyHandler(7680): SETUP(2) completed with result 0 (Success)
04-08 15:32:56.272: E/MediaPlayer(13688): error (1, -2147483648)
04-08 15:32:56.272: E/MediaPlayer(13688): Error (1,-2147483648)
04-08 15:32:56.272: D/VideoView(13688): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

I guess the problem is pointed with the "status: RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported transport", but I don't see what can I change : I already open the ports I use, and I do receive the video on another computer.

On the Android phone, I can play some rtsp streams I found on the web, for exemple this one : rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov .
So it should be possible.

If anyone can help... !

Comment: Did your problem get resolved??

Comment: I also want to develop an application which shows livestreaming of an IP camera. I have authenticated RSTP url which android's videoview not supporting. i also want to record RSTP ...can you guide me how to achive such functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally it was a network problem, I was connecting my devices through a MacBook WiFi sharing, and it seems that it blocked the RTSP stream. Now I am using a router and it works in RTSP (I'm still not able to receive a HTTP stream in the Android VideoView).
Nevertheless, I still have a timeout issue : the RTSP stream stops after 60 sec, because the VideoView doesn't send keep alive messages. I will try to do it myself...

Comment: So the error msg: status: RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported transport really mean it's network problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested my rtsp server with openRTSP command.

It's the UDP ports been blocked.

If accessing rtsp without -t:

```
-> $ openRTSP <rtsp_url>
```

I got log telling me:

```
// omit lots of lines..
Created receiver for "video/H264" subsession (client ports 63346-63347)
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://61.218.52.250:554/live/ch00_0/trackID=0 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.12.16)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=63346-63347

Received 47 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported Transport
CSeq: 4

Failed to setup "video/H264" subsession: 461 Unsupported Transport
```

So changing to TCP with:

```
-> $ openRTSP -t <rtsp_url>
```

it start receiving data successfully.

```
// omit lots of lines..
Opened URL "rtsp://61.218.52.250:554/live/ch00_0", returning a SDP description:
v=0
o=- 1 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Ubiquiti Live
i=UBNT Streaming Media
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 99
b=AS:50000
a=framerate:25
a=x-dimensions:1280,720
a=x-vendor-id:ubnt,a521
a=x-rtp-ts:4617405454576779984
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 profile-level-id=42A01E;packetization-mode=1;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAKOkAoAt1xIAG3dAAzf5gDYgQlA==,aM4xUg==
a=control:trackID=0

Sending request: SETUP rtsp://61.218.52.250:554/live/ch00_0/trackID=0 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.12.16)
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1


Received 107 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1
Session: E090B5503236A1BFB7CE


Setup "video/H264" subsession (client ports 54884-54885)
Sending request: PLAY rtsp://61.218.52.250:554/live/ch00_0/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: openRTSP (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.12.16)
Session: E090B5503236A1BFB7CE
Range: npt=0.000-


Received 159 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete PLAY response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Session: E090B5503236A1BFB7CE
Range: npt=now-
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://61.218.52.250:554/live/ch00_0//trackID=0;seq=41402;rtptime=0


Started playing session
Data is being streamed (signal with "kill -HUP 96432" or "kill -USR1 96432" to terminate)...
Received 47 new bytes of response data.
Received 1424 new bytes of response data.
Received 1424 new bytes of response data.
Received 1424 new bytes of response data.
Received 1424 new bytes of response data.
Received 1448 new bytes of response data.
Received 1448 new bytes of response data.
```

[Ref to openRTSP basics.](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/#other-options)

Now I've got to figure out how to auto switch to TCP in Android.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Sorry I've not touched that project for years. Last time I recalled the call would be stopped after a short period of time just like @tim-autin mentioned. Wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

please try the VLC:

vlc some_file.mp4 -I http --sout "#transcode{soverlay,ab=128,samplerate=44100,channels=2,acodec=mp4a,vcodec=h264,width=480,height=270,vfilter="canvas{width=480,height=270,aspect=16:9}",fps=25,vb=800,venc=x264{level=12,no-cabac,subme=20,threads=4,bframes=0,min-keyint=1,keyint=50}}:gather:rtp{mp4a-latm,sdp=rtsp://0.0.0.0:5554/stream.sdp}"

and the android code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);

        vidView.setVideoPath("rtsp://137.110.92.231:5554/stream.sdp");

        vidView.start();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **MediaPlayer** it supports both HTTP and RTSP network protocols.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations